# How do I architect my code to avoid this "Too many SOQL queries: 101"

Tags: apex, soql

I am developing some apex code that I am using to query a REST web service and storing resulting objects in salesforce.

I know that this error means that I am generating more than the 100 queries allowed but I am struggling to understand a way to avoid it...

So I make 3 Calls to this API. For each method I populate a list of corresponding objects and do an upsert at the end, I was running into the Callout error because I would upsert, callout, upsert... anyway

Call 1 : GetWebinars(integer lastXdays)
    Here I get a list of webinars over the last X days
Call 2 : GetSessions
    Here I get a list of Sessions associated to a given Webinar. 
Call 3 : GetAttendees
    Here I get a list of Attendees for a given sessions.

The problem is that these objects are linked. So if we look at GetAttendees, I have to loop through the list and do a lookup on the Contact object so that I can associate the contact to the attendee record.

Now currently I run this daily and there is only 1 Webinar per day with less than 50 Attendees but... I also have a query to associate the Attendee list to a give session and a session to a given webinar

So for 50 attendees I am already up to 52 queries. If my Webinar becomes popular and reached 99 attendees it'll break...

Is there a better way to do this? I am learning apex quick but am struggling to find the "right" way to do things.

Thanks

Comment: It is much easier to help you if you share the code in question. Please **[edit]** your post to include at least some example of it.

Comment: You may find some value in completing the [Bulk Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) unit on Trailhead, even if you are not building a trigger. The patterns are broadly applicable to code like this.

Comment: This is hard to provide an answer for without seeing your code, but can you do a SOQL query outside of your for loop get a list of attendees first? Then you can just iterate over this list without worrying about limits, as you can just use the relationship between the two.

Comment: Thanks for the input, after I posted I had a cup of coffee and realized that I should take my SOQL out of the for loop. In the end I have one SOQL query for each object that I store in a Map and then I search the map in the for loop for the 
correct key.

Here is a code snippet of what I have now.

map<Id, Contact> contacts = new map<Id, Contact>();
contacts.putAll([SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email in :emails]);         

for (ID idKey : contacts.keyset()) {
   if(a.email == contacts.get(idKey).Email)
      orgA.Contact__c = contacts.get(idKey).Id;                     
}

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input all, I was in fact executing SOQL inside a loop which I know is bad...

What I did to fix is populate a Map above the forloop with SOQL and then iterate through the Map in the loop. So only one SOQL query instead of X where X is the number of attendees.

```
map<Id, Contact> contacts = new map<Id, Contact>(); 
contacts.putAll([SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email in :emails]);                                                  

for(...){
     //do stuff here...
     for (ID idKey : contacts.keyset()) {
        if(a.email == contacts.get(idKey).Email)
        orgA.Contact__c = contacts.get(idKey).Id;                     
     } 
}
```